# How to convert text to money inside a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that displays information from a database, and I wish to convert the results to a money format.
This is the line I am attempting to convert:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderTotal", "{0:c}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

This doesn't work, and it does not error out.  Only whole numbers are displayed in the gridview.
Is there a way to do this preferably in the .aspx page?  If not, what will I need to do in order to convert every line to the Money format?

Thanks all!

Edit:
Entire Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="OrderID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" 
                    AllowPaging="True" style="margin-right: 3px" PageSize="50">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Select" Text="&gt;&gt; "></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order #" InsertVisible="False" 
                SortExpression="OrderID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="OrderDate">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderDate", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderAccount" HeaderText="Ordered By" 
                SortExpression="OrderAccount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderCostCentre" HeaderText="Cost Centre" 
                SortExpression="OrderCostCentre" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="OrderTotal">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("OrderTotal", "{0:c}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderTotal").ToString("C") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: can you show the markup of your gridview? are you using a boundcolumn?

Comment: capitalize the 'C' in your formatter string I think. "{0:C}"

Comment: Easy, apply the same Formula used to convert lead to gold... huh, you don't know that formula already? ;)

Comment: @Davide I have added my entire gridview code

Comment: @Eoin It still shows whole numbers :(

Comment: @Kolten- Check if the data type of the `OrderTotal` is a number. I've tested when column type is varchar and it doesn't work.

Comment: @nuux - Yes it is a varchar in the DB.  I will convert it to an int in the DB and try again tomorrow.  Hopefully, converting to an int won't mess up the rest of the application :S

Comment: @Kolten-yes that was the problem, I've posted an answer, you can accept it

Comment: @EoinCampbell For correctness' sake: the standard numeric format specifiers [are not case-sensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: @ kolten - sorry, shot in the dark / @djacobson - cheers good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `OrderTotal` is a non numeric type if so that is the problem. Convert it to a number and it should work

Answer (score 2):

Eval should work... Is there a reason you're using Eval on some and Bind on others?

```
<%#Eval("OrderTotal", "{0:c}")%>
```

Comment: First option I get "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'C'."
Second option won't compile.  
This seems like a good option if I can get it to work!  Any ideas?

Comment: @JeffTurner- Have you tested this BTW?

Comment: yeah sorry, forgot that the ToString method only works when dealing with it in the codebehind. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JeffTurner - No reason I'm using Eval() for that single OrderID entry.  Not sure why its like that.  I switched it to Bind() without issues.
Problem is - Your method doesn't convert it in any fashion.  It still shows as a whole number.  Curious as to why this isn't converting properly!